# How to stop GoLand from auto removal of unused imports?

Tags: go, goland

I am working with JetBrains GoLand and wondering if it's possible to somehow disable the auto removal of unused imports. I have searched the JetBrains forums earlier and there is no such information specifically for Goland.

[image: This picture shows the problem.]

Comment: The worst feature of goland, i've wasted a lot of time because of it :(

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This feature is used so that you do not receive compilation errors for unused imports from Go. You can deactivate the feature via:

*Settings (Preferences) > Go > Imports > Optimize imports on the fly*

However my recommendation is to leave this as is and instead let the IDE manage the imports for you.

For example, you can start typing `template.New` inside the `main` function and the IDE will ask which "template" package to import as there are two packages in the standard library "text/template" and "html/template". When only one package is available, that will be imported automatically. When you will remove the last reference to the "template" package, the IDE will remove the import automatically, thus allowing you to run the code without any compilation issues.

Comment: In newer versions of Goland or Intellij with Go plugin you might find this under "Languages & Frameworks > Go > Imports > Optimize..."

Comment: The IDE sometimes gets it wrong. For example, if I `import "rsc.io/quote/v4"` and then use `quote.Glass()` in my func, then GoLand deletes the import. But if I carefully not save, then right-click go.mod and do "GoModTidy", then it works fine. In contrast, VSCode even handles the save perfectly and does not delete the import.

Comment: I would like to actually get errors instead of some external thing automatically modifying my code. I also like manually formatting the files or places in code that were changed by me. The world is imperfect.

I started using GoLand recently in a legacy project and having this option by default just lost us several hours trying to figure it out.

Answer (score 13):

If disabling it doesn't work in `File | Settings | Go | Imports | Unchecked Optimized Imports On the fly` You can disable it in the on action Save menu

[image]

optimize imports enabled in File | Settings | Tools | Actions on Save | Uncheck Optimized Imports

REF: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/GO-6881/Goland-deletes-code-import-statements-are-deleted-automatically-before-I-even-get-an-opportunity-to-use-them#focus=Comments-27-6124465.0-0

Comment: I went to the setting with cmd + comma (on the menu Goland > Settings)

Answer (score 11):

Another solution is to name your import as "_". For example: `import _ "your/package"`. Doing this will prevent auto removal.

Comment: This is the only solution that worked for me, even after disabling all the import settings in the options it would still delete the imports as soon as I clicked on the terminal window to type `go get`

Answer (score 5):

The behavior was slightly changed in the 2021.2 version of GoLand and higher ([GO-11362](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/GO-11362)).

**Previous behavior (2021.1.3 and lower):**

[image]

**Current one (2021.2 and higher):**

[image]

So, it was slightly updated and there is no reason to disable *Optimize imports on the fly*, but as dlsniper said you can start typing your code and import packages later. It is a bit convenient way.

Comment: so seems like they reverted everything back to `(2021.1.3 and lower)` ... I have `GoLand 2022.2.4`

Comment: I like the auto optimization of the imports, but one thing I have noticed, is if I use something that requires an import, and the import gets added just fine, and then later I remove that something and nothing else is using that import, GoLand will grey out the import, but not remove it, and I get compile warnings.  Is there a way to have GoLand automatically remove imports no longer in use?

Answer (score 4):

Preferences:

- Languages & Frameworks

  - Go

    - Imports

      - Optimize imports on the fly

[image: Preferences]